# Wagtail user - minimal permissions to submit page for moderation?

Tags: wagtail

On wagtail, if I want to create a user that can edit a page and submit it for moderation, what are the user permissions I need to give a user for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Edit' permission over the given page is sufficient for this. See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for answering my n00b question :D